# MONGODB - Map all possible pairs from two different fields and count

Tags: mongodb, keyvaluepair

Here is a sample of my database:

[image: Sample]

What I have to do is getting all possible pairs of "start station name" and "end station name" and count with a sum all the made trips of this pair, then sort these pairs by the total of made trips.
I already know how to sum by group then sort. However, I don't know and haven't found if MongoDB has easy functions to make these unique value pairs.

The aim is to get the most used trips paths, and make recommandations following insights.

Comment: When you say 'all possible pairs' do you mean: Get all documents where in each one exists a pair, or, for `start station name` field in every document, check for every `end station name` in every document?

Comment: Can you post what have you tried till now?

Comment: @J.F. I mean exactly the second proposition. For example if there are 3 unique start station name [a,b,c] and 3 unique end station name [d,e,f], I want to get these pairs: (a,d);(a,e);(a,f);(b,d);(b;e);(b,f);(c,d);(c,e);(c,f). These pairs represent unique potential trips made

Comment: Sorry @wak786, but I tried with a group aggregation, but I've seen only that it can't work.. MapReduce should be done but I don't understand its structure.